# How to pass a function pointer to a method so that it can be used in Qt's connect()?

Tags: c++, qt, qaction, qt-slot

Background: I want to dynamically create the structure of a context menu and pass the slot of the action items to the method that creates the context menu.

The actual slot is in a QWidget class. I have tried different solutions by passing a function pointer. But they don't compile. Typical error message: "cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void (TextEdit::*)()'"

This compiles, but does not trigger the desired event:

```
MenuBuilder builder(&parentMenu);
auto *subMenu = builder.createMenu(SECTION, this, SLOT(TextEdit::onInsertChars()));
```

And the corresponding method:

```
QMenu *MenuBuilder::createMenu(const MenuDescription &menuDescription,
    const QObject *receiver, const char *target) {
    ...
    inlineMenu->addAction(text, receiver, target);
    ...
}
```

I'm sure there's an obvious solution, but I can't figure it out.

---

The solution: In this context you have to pass `SLOT(onInsertChars())` instead of `SLOT(TextEdit::onInsertChars())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto *subMenu = builder.createMenu(SECTION, this, SLOT(TextEdit::onInsertChars()));
```

The above should be:

```
auto *subMenu = builder.createMenu(SECTION, pointerToTheTextEdit, SLOT(onInsertChars()));
```

(of course if the `onInsertChars()` method is a slot in the class whose method is making the above call, then you can pass `this` as the pointer to the object that has the `onInsertChars()` slot)

Also, you may want to rename `const char * slot` in your `createMenu()` function to something else, as Qt's MOC preprocessor has kind of claimed the word `slot` for its own purposes and that might cause problems for you if you try to use it as a parameter name.  Maybe rename the parameter to `const char * slotName` or something instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. "this" is indeed the pointer to the object that contains the method onInsertChars(). To be on the safe side, I renamed the parameter "slot". But unfortunately that wasn't the solution.

Comment: Be sure to check your program's stdout/stderr output.  Usually when Qt fails to connect up a signal/slot connection, it will print a warning message there describing why it couldn't do it.

Comment: Yeah, you gave me the crucial hint! Everything is set correctly, but I was too busy with the compiler errors to pay attention to the stderror output, which states: "QObject::connect: No such slot TextEdit::TextEdit::onInsertChars()". Instead of SLOT(TextEdit::onInsertChars()) I have to pass SLOT(onInsertChars()).